# Manifest merger failed caused by an error with manifestPlaceholders in multimodule project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, placeholder, intentfilter

I have a little issue when trying to execute the androidUnitTest:

> "Manifest merger failed: Attribute data@scheme at
> manifestMerger8944498509061862801.xml requires a placeholder
> substitution but no value for  is provided"

In my Android module manifest I have this intent filter:

```
  <activity
            android:name="myactivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|keyboard|navigation"
            android:theme="@style/actionBarTheme"
            tools:node="replace">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="${urlScheme}"
                    android:host="action"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

and the manifestPlaceHolders are defined at the Gradle application level in the flavors.

I have tried to set the manifestPlaceHolder also in the module level, in that way the unit test go well, but in this way the intent filter when I run the app stop to working because in the merged file the URL scheme is the one defined in the module level